# How can I determine the number of objects that exist of a specific class?

Tags: python

What is the best way to return the number of existing objects of a class?

For instance, if I have constructed 4 MyClass objects, then the returned value should be 4. My personal use for this is an ID system. I want a class's constructor to assign the next ID number each time a new object of the class is constructed.

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: Why not make another class called "Creator" or something, and give that class a counter object and a method that creates and returns new MyClass objects? Then each time Creator is asked to create a MyClass, it increments its internal counter and then does so?

Comment: member variable in a factory object?

*EDIT* lol EMS answered while I was answering, but yeah

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just create a int that keeps track of the count as you create the object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just manage a counter in the class scope:

```
import itertools

class MyClass(object):
    get_next_id = itertools.count().next

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = self.get_next_id()
```

This will assign a new ID to every instance:

```
>>> MyClass().id
0
>>> MyClass().id
1
>>> MyClass().id
2
>>> MyClass().id
3
```

Comment: Don't think this would work. Each class would have it's own `count` member so when you do `someInstant.count` you'll always get `1`. Different instantiations of classes do not share members.

*EDIT* Oh just saw the update, this should work.

Comment: @kstruct: Of course this is a per-class counter. I thought this was asked? The update didn't change anything semantically.

Comment: FWIW I always use a class-level itertools.count() instance for this, and get a new id through next().

Comment: @DSM: Nice idea. Gonna steal it from you!

Comment: @DSM This is still more complicated than it needs to be. Just do `id_counter = itertools.count().next` and then `def __init__(self): self.id = self.id_counter()`. No `classmethod` necessary, and the `self.__class__` instead of just `self` is superfluous.

Comment: @agf: myself, I use "id_counter = itertools.count()" and "self.id = next(self.id_counter)"; for some reason I prefer writing next(something) rather than x=something.next; x().

Comment: @agf: Right, it's late already... Gotta get some sleep, obviously, thanks for the follow-up.

Answer (score 2):

"What is the best way to return the number of existing objects of a class?"

The exact answer I think is "There is no way" because you can not make sure whether the object that created by the class has been recycled by python's garbage collection mechanism.

So if we really want to know the existing objects, we first should make it existing by holding them on a class level attribute when they are created:

```
class AClass(object):
    __instance = []

    def __init__(self):
        AClass.__instance.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def count(cls):
        return len(cls.__instance)
```